# Continuity of this function as $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Here's a function in $x$ and $y$ defined piecewise as
> $$f(x,y)=
> \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
>       0 & (x,y)=(0,0)\\
>  \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
> \end{array}\right.$$
> Examine its continuity as the ordered pair tends to $(0,0)$.

Okay, so I first tried this by assuming $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and $y=\frac{1}{n^2}$, where $n\rightarrow \infty$ . The limit of the function as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ came out to be $\frac{1}{2}$, and since this is not equal to the value of the function at the said point, its discontinuous at the origin.
But when I assumed $x=\frac{1}{n}$  and $y=\frac{1}{n}$ , I got the limit zero:$$f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})= \frac{\frac{1}{n^3}}{\frac{1}{n^4}+ \frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n^2}+ 1} $$
 Since $x,y \rightarrow 0$,$f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow \frac{0}{0+1}=0$
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. Why can't the limits be different along different curves?

Comment: With your results, decide if f is continuos at (0,0).

Comment: You may use the curve $r_{\alpha}(t)=(t,\alpha t^2)$.

Comment: I had just entered multivariable calculus, in fact, the very next line of my book had the answer- I believe its discontinuous because the limits are different along different paths. Its all sorted now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you get different values along different paths, you can conclude that the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$$

does not exist. If the limit does not even exist, there is no way it can equal $f(0,0)$, and so the function cannot be continuous at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that :
$$f(t, t^2) = \dfrac{t^2 t^2}{t^4 + t^2} = \dfrac{t^4}{2 t^4} = \dfrac{1}{2} \underset{t \to 0}{\to} \dfrac{1}{2} \neq f(0, 0)$$